# How to trigger bootstrap modal programatically in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Onclick of a button i need to validate some data, if it is true then i need to open modal or no. But in my condition modal is opening for every click unable to it programatically

```
function verifyOtp(){
   if(sucsess){}
   else{}
}
    
<button onClick={()}=>verifyOtp() data-toggle="modal" data-target="#successModal">
</button>

    <div  className="modal fade" id="successModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby = "emailModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"> 
            <div className="modal-dialog email-modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div className="modal-content verify-modal-dialog">
                    <div className="modal-header email-modal-header">
                        <button type="button" className="close"  data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>                  
                    <p className="modal-title email-modal-title" id="emailModalLabel">Succesfull</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Need to use State here is the working-class component example of a model. if you are using functional components then use useState() hook instead of  this.setState() method

```
    import React from "react";
        
        export default class AddNewList extends React.Component {
          state = {
            showModal: false
          };
        
          closeModal = () => {
            this.setState({ showModal: false });
          };
        
          onSave = () => {
            console.log("i saved the data.");
            this.setState({ showModal: false });
          };
          verifyOtp = () => {
            //your success value
            if (true) {
              this.setState({ showModal: true });
            }
          };
        
          render() {
            return (
              <>
                <div>
                  <button onClick={this.verifyOtp} className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
                    Open Modal
                  </button>
                </div>
                {this.state.showModal && (
                  <div className="" id="addnewlist">
                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                      <div className="modal-content">
                        <div className="modal-header">
                          <h4 className="modal-title"> Model Header</h4>
                        </div>
        
                        <div className="modal-body">
                          test
                        </div>
        
                        <div className="modal-footer">
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            className="btn btn-danger"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                            onClick={this.closeModal}
                          >
                            Close
                          </button>
                          <button
                            type="button"
                            className="btn btn-outline-success"
                            onClick={this.onSave}
                          >
                            Save
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
              </>
            );
          }
        }
```

Skeleton for the functional component

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
    const [showModel,setShowModel] = useState(false);
    function AddNewList (){
    closeModal = () => {
            setShowModel(false);
                  };
        
          onSave = () => {
            setShowModel(false);
          };
          verifyOtp = () => {
            //your success value
            if (true) {
              setShowModel(true);
            }
          };
    return render();
    }
```

Comment: @SanjeevKumar share your code with methods.

Comment: Remove this div <div  className="modal fade" id="successModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby = "emailModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

Comment: function verifyOtp(){       
        if(firstInput!=='' && secondInput!=='' && thirdInput!==''&&fourthInput!==''&&fifthInput!==''&&sixthInput!==''){
            setSuccessModal(true)
        }else{
            alert('Please fill all the fields')
            setSuccessModal(false);
        }
    }
{sucessOtpModal && (Modal code here)}

Comment: What console says

Comment: check your input values over the console and also check the show model value.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/close-modal-bootstrap-forked-s6pcd?file=/src/AddNewList.js
I'm running your model code here and it's work for me. I think the problem is with your input fields values